# Error: can not find JSP view file in Spring Boot and Gradle

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, build.gradle

I'm using Spring Boot in Gradle, when I run Application class, it can not load JSP file in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp folder.

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {   
ext { 
        springBootVersion = '1.0.2.RELEASE' 
} 
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
    classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.1.RELEASE")
  }
 }

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'war'  

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
}

dependencies {    
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}") 
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-solr', version: '1.1.0.RELEASE'
compile("javax.servlet:jstl:1.2")
runtime("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:${springBootVersion}")
compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:${springBootVersion}")
providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:8.0.27'

}
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class HomePageController {

@RequestMapping(value="/homepage")
public String getHomePage(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                          HttpServletResponse response,
                                          ModelMap model) {             
    return "index";
 }  
}
```

application.properties:

```
#Spring Security authentication
security.basic.enabled=false

# SPRING MVC
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
server.port=8080
```

Log message:

```
2017-03-19 14:04:46,378 DEBUG DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/homepage]
2017-03-19 14:04:46,379 DEBUG Looking up handler method for path /homepage
2017-03-19 14:04:46,379 DEBUG Did not find handler method for [/homepage]
2017-03-19 14:04:46,379 DEBUG Matching patterns for request [/homepage] are [/**]
2017-03-19 14:04:46,380 DEBUG URI Template variables for request [/homepage] are {}
2017-03-19 14:04:46,380 DEBUG Mapping [/homepage] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@72d49bcb] and 1 interceptor
2017-03-19 14:04:46,380 DEBUG Last-Modified value for [/homepage] is: -1
2017-03-19 14:04:46,380 DEBUG Trying relative path [homepage] against base location: ServletContext resource [/]
2017-03-19 14:04:46,381 DEBUG Trying relative path [homepage] against base location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
2017-03-19 14:04:46,381 DEBUG Trying relative path [homepage] against base location: class path resource [resources/]
2017-03-19 14:04:46,382 DEBUG Trying relative path [homepage] against base location: class path resource [static/]
2017-03-19 14:04:46,382 DEBUG Trying relative path [homepage] against base location: class path resource [public/]
2017-03-19 14:04:46,382 DEBUG No matching resource found - returning 404
2017-03-19 14:04:46,382 DEBUG Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-03-19 14:04:46,382 DEBUG Successfully completed request
```

Exception happened when **updated** latest version:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'beanFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:223)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:702)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
at com.totoroads.solr.configure.Application.main(Application.java:40)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:923)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:804)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:558)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:432)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:220)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1260)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
... 19 common frames omitted
```

How to fix this error? thank so much.

Comment: Try removing the `@Scope` from your controller and see what happens. Good for you for including the log messages.

Comment: (I'll note that one of the great benefits of Spring Boot is removing a lot of the setup overhead for Java Web applications, and I suggest not using war packaging and leaving templates in the default `src/main/resources/templates` directory. Neither of those is your problem here, though.)

Comment: @chrylis, thanks for recommend, in some case if no use /resources/templates is still fine, I will try use templates. I have removed annotation@Scope yet and it same error :(

Comment: because I only use jsp and jstl in my project so I'll not use template, isn't it ?

Comment: Spring Boot 1.0.2 uses Tomcat 7, but you've added Jasper from Tomcat 8. 1.0.2 is also really old. I'd recommend upgrading to the latest version of Spring Boot and leaving it to manage the versions of your dependencies.

Comment: Thank @AndyWilkinson: I know v1.0.2 is old and want to upgrading latest version, but I'm maintaining my project, so can I still use v1.0.2 with tomcat7 ? please for me advice if using 1.0.2 and tomcat 7..

Comment: I have updated Spring Boot latest(1.5.2), and then it happen an exception..

Comment: Hi @AndyWilkinson, chrylis:  after an hour I have fixed this error, I use latest version and it worked ! thank so much